# Outputting to Excel and overwriting exisiting tab

Tags: python, excel

I have a Python program where I use SQL to extract the data and now I need to write it to an existing Excel file. This new data should overwrite an existing tab (same name), keep the other two intact so I can use the formulas in the other two tabs on an the updated data.

I would appreciate sample code to help me do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to a .csv file by knowing the row and column i want to write to. This is the function:

```
import csv

def write_csv_cell(filename, row, column, data):
    """This one is solely for .csv files"""
    # read the csv file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        mylist = list(reader)
    
    # edit the data
    mylist[row][column] = str(data)

    # (over)write the csv file
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
        csv_writer.writerows(mylist)

import openpyxl

def write_xlsx_cell(file_name, sheet_name, cell=None, data=None):
    """And this one for xlsx files. Install package with pip (python -m pip install openpyxl)"""
    # open workbook
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    print(f"This workbook has the following sheets: {book.sheetnames}")
    
    # select sheet
    sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    print(f"You selected {sheet.title}")

    # read cell value
    old_value = sheet[cell].value
    
    # modify cell
    sheet[cell] = data
    print(f"Changed sheet {sheet_name} cell {cell} from {old_value} to {sheet[cell].value}")

    # save/overwrite workbook
    book.save(file_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_xlsx_cell(file_name="test.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", cell="A1", data="Hey, test")
```

Comment: Not sure about that but i think that if you modify a .xlsx it destroys all the macros and formulas. I think @Paula should use some vba.

Comment: This is only for .csv files. For xlsx, try the xlrd package, they have examples too: https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/

Comment: Edited my answer and added a function for xlsx